# CDK deploy results in "Bucket named 'x' exists, but not in account 067685711111. Wrong account?"

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am modifying a CDK pipeline that works. I am adding a lambda, and when this code modification is made, the pipeline fails with an error.

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as lambda from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda';
import * as path from 'path';
import { Rule, Schedule } from '@aws-cdk/aws-events';
import { LambdaFunction } from '@aws-cdk/aws-events-targets';
import { Secret } from '@aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager';
import { Effect, Policy, PolicyStatement } from '@aws-cdk/aws-iam';

interface LambdaStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
    logzioToken: string;
}

export class Lambda extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: LambdaStackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const logzioSecret = Secret.fromSecretAttributes(this, 'sv-logzioToken', {
            secretPartialArn: props.logzioToken,
        });

        // Here is the func itself
        const func = new lambda.Function(this, 'sv-http-cache-clear-lambda', {
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
            handler: 'index.handler',
            // The "build" folder requires `yarn build` to have been run in the lambda folder
            code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, '../../lambdas/HttpCacheClear/build')),
            environment: {
                LOGZIO_TOKEN: logzioSecret.secretValueFromJson('logzioToken').toString(),
            },
        });

        // Here are the Dynamo permissions I think we need
        const policyStatement = new PolicyStatement({
            actions: ['dynamodb:GetItem', 'dynamodb:Query', 'dynamodb:Scan', 'dynamodb:DeleteItem'],
            effect: Effect.ALLOW,
            resources: ['*'],
        });
        const policy = new Policy(this, 'sv-http-cache-clear-policy', {
            statements: [policyStatement],
        });
        func.role?.attachInlinePolicy(policy);

        new Rule(this, 'sv-http-cache-clear-schedule-rule', {
            description: 'Schedule a Lambda that regularly clears the cache',
            schedule: Schedule.cron({
                year: '*',
                month: '*',
                day: '*',
                hour: '1',
                minute: '0',
            }),
            targets: [new LambdaFunction(func)],
        });
    }
}
```

This is instantiated in the CDK from here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import 'source-map-support/register';
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { AppStack } from '../lib/app-stack';
import { ECR } from '../lib/ecr';
import { Lambda } from '../lib/lambda';
import { getConfig } from '../lib/config';

const app = new cdk.App();

// Stateful infra
const { repository } = new ECR(app, 'sv-ecr-stack');

// Get app config
const environment = process.env.ENVIRONMENT || '';
const { certificateArn, domainName, sIdProgramId, logzioToken, optimizelyUrl } = getConfig(environment);

new AppStack(app, 'sv-stack', {
    repository,
    domainName,
    certificateArn,
    sIdProgramId,
    logzioToken,
    optimizelyUrl,
    environment,
});

const lambda = new Lambda(app, 'sv-http-scheduled-cache-clear', {
    logzioToken,
});
```

For reasons of brevity I have not added the `AppStack` to this post.

Finally I have a fairly simple set of NPM dependencies:

```
{
    "name": "cdk",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "bin": {
        "cdk": "bin/cdk.js"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
        "watch": "tsc -w",
        "cdk": "cdk",
        "synth": "cdk synth -q",
        "deploy": "cdk deploy --all --progress=events --require-approval=never"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@aws-cdk/assert": "^1.100.0",
        "@aws-cdk/aws-certificatemanager": "^1.100.0",
        "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2": "^1.100.0",
        "@aws-cdk/aws-ecr": "^1.100.0",
        "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs": "^1.100.0",
        "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs-patterns": "^1.100.0",
        "@aws-cdk/aws-iam": "^1.100.0",
        "@aws-cdk/aws-route53": "^1.100.0",
        "@types/node": "10.17.27",
        "aws-cdk": "^1.100.0",
        "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
        "typescript": "~3.9.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@aws-cdk/core": "^1.100.0",
        "source-map-support": "^0.5.16"
    }
}
```

If I run `npm run synth` locally then it runs the synth command, and succeeds. I have no TypeScript errors in my editor.

Here is the `cdk deploy` error:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$DEV_ACCESS_KEY_ID
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$DEV_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
export ENVIRONMENT=dev
cd cdk
npm install
npm run deploy

npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm WARN cdk@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN cdk@0.1.0 No license field.

added 1363 packages from 232 contributors and audited 1366 packages in 19.228s

18 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities


> cdk@0.1.0 deploy /home/circleci/project/cdk
> cdk deploy --all --progress=events --require-approval=never

sv-ecr-stack
sv-ecr-stack: deploying...

 ✅  sv-ecr-stack (no changes)

Outputs:
sv-ecr-stack.ExportsOutputFnGetAttsvrepositoryXXX = arn:aws:ecr:*********:067685711111:repository/student-validation-app
sv-ecr-stack.ExportsOutputRefsvrepositoryXXX = student-validation-app

Stack ARN:
arn:aws:cloudformation:*********:067685711111:stack/sv-ecr-stack/aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkk
sv-http-scheduled-cache-clear
sv-http-scheduled-cache-clear: deploying...
[0%] start: Publishing abcdefghijklmnop:current
[100%] fail: Bucket named 'cdktoolkit-stagingbucket-7k57fjeur592' exists, but not in account 067685711111. Wrong account?

 ❌  sv-http-scheduled-cache-clear failed: Error: Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
    at Object.publishAssets (/home/circleci/project/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/util/asset-publishing.ts:25:11)
    at Object.deployStack (/home/circleci/project/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/deploy-stack.ts:235:3)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (/home/circleci/project/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:180:24)
    at initCommandLine (/home/circleci/project/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.ts:208:9)
***************************************************
*** Newer version of CDK is available [1.110.0] ***
*** Upgrade recommended                         ***
***************************************************
Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cdk@0.1.0 deploy: `cdk deploy --all --progress=events --require-approval=never`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the cdk@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2021-06-25T13_34_37_706Z-debug.log


Exited with code exit status 1
```

A bit of research indicates that CDK uses S3 to create a "staging bucket", and I assume that is what the `cdktoolkit-stagingbucket-*` is (it is not an artifact that I have created explicitly).

Do I need to create this bucket remotely/explicitly or locally/manually?

### Update

I have found [this bug report](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6808) which suggests that the error message is terrible - it needs S3 access but the message does not make that clear. I have found this policy file for the CI/CD user, and I wonder if I need to work out what policy to add to it to permit S3 usage.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "StmtXXXYYYZZZ4501",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:*",
                "ec2:*",
                "ecs:*",
                "ecr:*",
                "application-autoscaling:*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:*",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:TagRole",
                "iam:UpdateRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "logs:*",
                "route53:*",
                "secretsmanager:*",
                "sts:*",
                "dynamodb:*",
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is rather misleading. The S3 bucket is highly likely to exist in another account if you have access to several accounts - this is because it is an auto-generated bucket that is used by CDK to package and deploy lambdas. I assume it is the same name in all AWS accounts.

The simple solution is to add `"s3:*"` to your allowed actions against a `"*"` resource. However, I decided to add a new Policy so that the resource specification was a little tighter. In my case this meant adding a new clause with a different resource specification:

```
{
    "Action": [
        "s3:*"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cdktoolkit-stagingbucket-*"
}
```

It looks like you don't have to explicitly create this bucket - CDK will do it for you. It appears also that the "Sid" is not a mandatory field.

In my case, adding this Policy revealed how many other permissions I was missing, but at least the error message for those was more sensible!

Comment: where to add this permission , is it for cdk deploy role ?

Comment: @ravthiru: for this project the IAM user was set up manually with [this JSON config](https://gist.github.com/halfer/1481d99d8599521a9f72139805dca839). I believe you can create an IAM role in the console and then just paste in the config (obviously edit it to suit). From there you can set up your access key and secret access key in your CI secrets.

Comment: (I am sure one can do this sort of thing in CDK itself, though for reasons I don't recall, it was manual for this project).

Answer (score 3):

The action that triggers that error is `s3:GetBucketLocation`. A policy that only provides minimal permissions the CDK needs would be:

```
{
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cdktoolkit-stagingbucket-*",
    "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

Comment: That sounds about right. The problem I think I had was that the error was a million miles away from saying what it needed. Any idea if they fixed that error now? We're only four months on, so I would expect not.